# Best practice: Static block on Category page

Tags: magento2, category, static-block, magento-2.0.7, best-practice

I want to place a full width static block at the bottom of the category page (of every category). I am quite new to Magento 2, and I was wondering what the best practice is for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Create the static block in the Magento admin.

Step 2: In [Your Theme Folder]/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml add the following (Your static block name can be whatever you like):

```
<referenceContainer name="content.bottom">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="[Your_Static_Block_Name]">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="block_id"  xsi:type="string">[Your_Static_Block_Id]</argument>
    </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```